# how to fix legend in pie chart rstudio

Tags: r

```
pie(table(games_list$Genre),
    main = "Rating Pie Chart",
    col=brewer.pal(length(games_list$Genre),'Spectral'))

legend("topright",
       legend=row.names(games_list$Genre), 
       fill = brewer.pal(length(games_list$Rating), 'Spectral'))
```

> Error in legend("topright", legend = row.names(games_list$Genre), fill = brewer.pal(length(games_list$Rating),  : 
>     'legend' is of length 0

Answer (score 0):

Check that `row.names(games_list$Genre)` returns something and is what the `legend` parameter expects.

Because you did not provide sample data, I am using the `iris` dataset in the example below:

```r
pie(table(iris$Species),
    main = "Rating Pie Chart",
    col=brewer.pal(
      length(unique(iris$Species)), # we need only unique values
      'Spectral'
      )
    )

legend("topright",
       legend=unique(iris$Species),
       fill = brewer.pal(
         length(unique(iris$Species)),
         'Spectral'
         )
       )
```

The code above produces:
[image: sample pie using base graphics in R]

As an aside, if you have more than 2 or 3 types/classes you want to show, better use barcharts. Here is a good write up by Stephen Few on this topic ["Save the Pies for Dessert"](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf)